# SQL sum formula vs jquery formula?

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, html-table

I need to calculate sum and average in html table, my question is which is better, does one have huge advantages over the other? thanks!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! if you want to get other's attention & helpful answer, you should make your question plentiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, heavy lifting of data which originates in a database should be done in the database itself, and not in the application layer.  This would certainly be true, e.g., if the table in question had thousands (or more) of records.  That being said, if your jQuery view only shows a few dozen records, and you need to do aggregations or other similar things in the page itself, then there is nothing wrong with doing that.

Another point to consider here is the bandwidth which is consumed when data gets sent across the network from the database to your application.  It is desirable to *not* send data which you do not really need.  This might occur if you were sending certain data only for the purpose of aggregating it in your application layer, and displaying those aggregates to the user.  In this case, it would be preferable to crunch the data on the database, and then just send the results to the application.

Comment: that's the information I was looking for, currently using jquery, mysql is giving errors when I use the sum function,  I'm using oop pdo, probably misplacing a word, I'll post the code later in a new question, to see if anyone can spot what's wrong with it.